# The goods of forcing the user to follow a path

Tags: website-design, layout, scrolling, marketing, fullscreen

Maybe this is not the best place to ask as this seems to me like a question regarding two fields: marketing and user experience.

Hopefully some of my questions could be solved from the user experience point of view.

I've seen recently many *important* sites using the mouse hijacking technique to create some full screen scrollable sites, such as:

- [Google](http://www.google.com/calendar/about/)
- Apple (in its old iPhone 5C site)
- [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/)
- [Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/)
- [Facebook](http://facebookgroups.com)
- [Sony](http://www.sony-asia.com/microsite/mdr-10/)

Clearly, besides all the popular believe about the bads of using those kind of sites, **there is something GOOD about it**.

All those sites are in one way or another an advert kind of site. Trying to sell or show somehow the benefits of their product. 
Small texts, big and beautiful images...

They can all be wrong about it, but I like to believe these companies has great UX and marketing teams and that they know what they are doing when they decide to go for one or another design for their products.

Marketing has its own books and rules, and I'm pretty sure there's something good about this design oriented to marketing.

Just wondering if somebody could point me to some articles about the topic or name some benefits from the UX point of view **taking into consideration they are all advert sites**.

I'm not expecting to read anything about its `responsive` problems and so on. If the site is designed properly, those shouldn't happen.

Comment: Haven't you asked this [before](http://ux.stackexchange.com/q/66451/36883)?

Comment: Now I'm asking more about the pros of using it in advert kind of websites. Nothing about he cons :) As it seems the cons are not enough for those companies to reject those kind of sites.